# Webpack.config.js: Configuration has an unknown property 'default'

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I've moved everything over from a working project (ultimate-hot-reloading-example), to an existing project of mine that uses the keystone cms. I uninstalled ALL dev dependencies in my project, and installed all of the exact dependencies in the working project into mine (webpack, babel, etc...).

For some reason, the web.config.js file won't parse the es6 syntax

```
export default
```

Which gives this error:

```
- configuration has an unknown property 'default'.
```

If I switch to the following, it works:

```
const config = ...
module.exports = config;
```

Elsewhere in my project, I use other es6 syntax and it works...

Here's the dependencies in package.json, which works perfectly with the example project with the 'export default' syntax.

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
"babel-core": "^6.10.4",
"babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
"babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
"babel-register": "^6.9.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
"chokidar": "^2.0.3",
"css-loader": "^0.28.11",
"css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.1",
"eslint": "^4.19.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.1",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"prop-types": "^15.6.1",
"react": "^16.3.2",
"react-dom": "^16.3.2",
"react-hot-loader": "^4.1.3",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"style-loader": "^0.21.0",
"webpack": "^4.8.3",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.1",
"webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
```

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: webpack runs on node, you can't use es6 syntax there. You must either tell a CLI to parse it, or use CJS

Comment: @PlayMa256 I am using babel to parse it. As I stated, it's strange because all other es6 syntax parses correctly in my project. I think I'm having a babel version conflict, due to the babel dependencies installed by keystone cms and the one installed by me...

Comment: How are you running the cli? passing the config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem which turned to be my improper migration from `require(...)` to `import(...)`

I replaced this code:

```js
const common = require("./webpack.common");
module.exports = merge(common, {...})
```

with:

```js
const common = await import("./webpack.common.js");
export default merge(common, .....)
```

The problem was that I didn't use the `default` export from `webpack.common.js`. The fix is:

```js
const common = await import("./webpack.common.js");
export default merge(common.default, .....)
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I was working on this project. However, I opened an old copy. I actually had another workaround I came up with, but I tested the validity of this for the sake of others. It seems to work. Very interesting. Thanks